# custom page size in pdfbox?

Tags: java, pdfbox, grails-2.2

In pdfbox is there a way to set a custom page size for example 6" x 8". This is the size of runner bib card. The only sizes that seem to be available are the following:

```
 ReportPageSize pageSize = ReportPageSize.AVERY_5160;
 PdfDocInfo doc = new PdfDocInfo(pageSize)
```

[image]

I appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 2):

pass a mediabox when creating your page:

```
private static final float POINTS_PER_INCH = 72;

PDPage page = new PDPage(
    new PDRectangle(6 * POINTS_PER_INCH, 8 * POINTS_PER_INCH));
```

"PdfDocInfo" is not from PDFBox.